# Jenkins / Hudson createItem API request returning white space error

Tags: api, rest, jenkins, hudson, hudson-api

I am trying to submit a POST to the Jenkins API to create a new job. I followed the API documentation and am using Postman to make the specific request.

When I make the request, the server returns `ERROR 500` and the following errors:

```
<html><head><title>Error 500</title></head>
```

## Status Code: 500

Exception: Unable to read /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Tes234t6.dev/config.xml
Stacktrace:

```
hudson.util.IOException2: Unable to read /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Tes234t6.dev/config.xml
    at hudson.XmlFile.read(XmlFile.java:145)
    at hudson.model.Items.load(Items.java:220)
    at hudson.model.ItemGroupMixIn.createProjectFromXML(ItemGroupMixIn.java:235)
    at hudson.model.ItemGroupMixIn.createTopLevelItem(ItemGroupMixIn.java:167)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doCreateItem(Jenkins.java:2876)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:288)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:151)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:90)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:111)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:677)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:770)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:583)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:214)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:45)
    at winstone.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:248)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:376)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:95)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:87)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ApiTokenFilter.doFilter(ApiTokenFilter.java:64)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:50)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:331)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:227)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:  : only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not - (position: START_DOCUMENT seen -... @1:1) 
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.pullNextEvent(XppReader.java:124)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.readRealEvent(AbstractPullReader.java:148)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.readEvent(AbstractPullReader.java:141)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.move(AbstractPullReader.java:118)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.moveDown(AbstractPullReader.java:103)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.<init>(XppReader.java:63)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractXppDriver.createReader(AbstractXppDriver.java:54)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractXppDriver.createReader(AbstractXppDriver.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:925)
    at hudson.XmlFile.read(XmlFile.java:143)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not - (position: START_DOCUMENT seen -... @1:1) 
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1519)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1395)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.pullNextEvent(XppReader.java:109)
    ... 75 more
```

---

*Generated by Stapler at Fri Jun 07 10:47:55 EDT 2013*

Ive taken a look at my config.xml file and there is no whitespace at the top of the file. Other than that, I am not sure what it is talking about. I have googled and looked on SO but without finding anything relating to using this API outside of CLI. Any have any experience doing this sucessfully or and pointers?

This is the post request I am making to the API:

```
POST /createItem?name=Tes234t6.dev HTTP/1.1
Host: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080
Content-Type: text/xml
Authorization: Basic cm9vdDpjcm9zYnlhZG0xbg==
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="config.xml"; filename="config.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml


----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

Answer (score 0):

So turns out despite the Jenkins API saying to post "config.xml" you arent actually sending a file, but posting the xml data itself.

The way I did this was using the Postman plugin for chrome, and adding the contents of my config.xml file directly to the RAW input. This worked for me.

Hope this saves some other people some frustration.

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon this issue but your solution did not work for us. So, if anyone googles this issue here is an other possible solution.

We had a **Apache** in front of our **Jenkins** (connected via AJP). When using Jeknins version `1.534` (or below), everything worked fine. After upgrading to `1.535` or above, we got the error mentioned above when trying to create a job via the REST-API. This did not happen all the time, but in 1 of 20 job creations.

As it turned out, this only happened when the REST-API was invoked via Apache (and then forwarded to Jeknins using ajp). The solution was to directly make REST calls against the Jenkins.

---

Note: [jenkins `1.535` and above is using Jetty 8.](http://jenkins-ci.org/changelog#v1.535)